# return statement vs. print statement?

Tags: python, printing, return

Can someone explain why this code only prints 6? :)

```
def func(x):
    result = 0
    for i in range(x):
        result = result + i
    return result

print(func(4))
```

Comment: Because that's what it's supposed to do. It's printing the return value of the function. The range is exclusive, so 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

Comment: Try `print(func(1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since your code isn't formatted right in the question and I can't edit it due to a pending edit (which I bet fixes it), I'm going to assume your code is supposed to look like this:

```
def func(x):
    result = 0
    for i in range(x):
        result = result + i
    return result

print(func(4))
```

Lets break it down step by step.  Your print will call `func`, give it the number 4, and then print whatever number comes out.  So control jumps to `func` and begins processing there, with the number 4 for `x`.  You initialize result to 0, and then enter the loop.  `for i in range(x)` will get you a list of numbers `[0, 1, 2, 3]` (not actually a list, but we can treat it this way for this simplified explanation). For each number `i` in that list, you are adding it to the current value of `result`.  So `result` goes through these steps:

```
result = 0 + 0
result = 0 + 1
result = 1 + 2
result = 3 + 3
```

The final value of `result` is 6, which is returned, and printed.  That is where your 6 is coming from.  If you call `func(5)`, you will get 10, since it goes through the same steps, but adds an additional 4 to the same computation.  What this function does is add the numbers from `0` up to `x - 1` (at least for positive integer inputs).

Comment: Oh, I understand. I just assumed that it would return all the results and not just the last one. So, I expected to see:. 0 1 3 6.